# How to achieve concurrency with two threads with different execution times?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, logging, io

I am working on a school project. I set some rules in `iptables` which logs INPUT and OUTPUT connections. My goal is to read these logs line by line, parse them and find out which process with which PID is causing this.

My problem starts when I use `psutil` to find a match with `(ip, port)` tuple with the corresponding PID. `iptables` is saving logs to file too fast, like `1x10^-6 seconds`. My Python script also read lines as fast as `iptables`. But when I use the following code:

```
def get_proc(src: str, spt: str, dst: str, dpt: str) -> str:
    proc_info = ""

    if not (src and spt and dst and dpt):
        return proc_info

    for proc in psutil.process_iter(["pid", "name"]):
        for conn in proc.connections(kind="all"):
            if flag.is_set():
                return proc_info
            if not all([
                hasattr(conn.laddr, "ip"), hasattr(conn.laddr, "port"),
                hasattr(conn.raddr, "ip"), hasattr(conn.raddr, "port"),
            ]):
                continue
            if not all([
                conn.laddr.ip == src, conn.laddr.port == int(spt),
                conn.raddr.ip == dst, conn.raddr.port == int(dpt),
            ]):
                continue
            return f"pid={proc.pid},name={proc.name()}"

    return proc_info
```

`psutil` finishes its job like `1x10^-3 seconds`, means `10^3` times slower than reading process. What happens is that: If I run this `get_proc` function `once`, I read `1000` lines. So this slowness quickly becomes a problem when `1x10^6` lines are read at the end. Because in order to find the PID, I need to run this method immediately when the log is received.

I thought of using `multithreading` but as far as I understand it won't solve my problem. Because the same latency problem.

I haven't done much coding so far because I still can't find an algorithm to use. That's way no more code here.

How can I solve this problem with or without `multithreading`? Because I can't speed up the execution of `psutil`. I believe there must be better approaches.

### Edit

Code part for reading logs from `iptables.log`:

```
flag = threading.Event()


def stop(signum, _frame):
    """
    Tell everything to stop themselves.

    :param signum: The captured signal number.
    :param _frame: No use.
    """
    if flag.is_set():
        return
    sys.stderr.write(f"Signal {signum} received.")
    flag.set()


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop)


def receive_logs(file, queue__):
    global CURSOR_POSITION

    with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as _f:
        _f.seek(CURSOR_POSITION)

        while not flag.is_set():
            line = re.sub(r"[\[\]]", "", _f.readline().rstrip())
            if not line:
                continue

            # If all goes okay do some parsing...
            # .
            # .

            queue__.put_nowait((nettup, additional_info))

    
    CURSOR_POSITION = _f.tell()
```

Comment: What you try to achieve has an inherent race condition. Both the port-ip combination as well as the process ID could have been reassigned by the time you process it. You can become faster to make it less likely but that is an inherent issue of the entire approach. If it makes you feel better, you aren't the only one suffering from this design issue https://lwn.net/Articles/754980/

Comment: I believe the correct approach is to use the audit subsystem in Linux because that can get all the information in one go. But that may also be somewhat involved https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP4/html/SLES-all/cha-audit-comp.html

Comment: @Homer512 Unfortunately using `audit` is not an option for me because I was told to do it with `iptables`. And I was told that if I ran into a design problem, I had to fix them.

Comment: One more thing: Two or more processes can share the same open socket (open the socket, then ```fork()```). So you might find multiple candidates.

Comment: Is your main issue that you cannot keep up with the number of log messages or that processes are already gone before you could find them? In other words, do you need to optimize throughput or latency? Because for the first issue you can use one scan through the process list to search for multiple connections and I can formulate an answer to help with that. The second issue is harder to fix

Comment: @Homer512 Yes, I cannot keep up. My `get_proc` function is slow to process input. For example, when the `1` log is processed, the new `1000` logs have already arrived.

Comment: I mean there is a chance to fail finding PID from connections. Because most of these connections are short lived. And because of this `1` to `1000` problem I will always fail finding the PIDs of newer connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that may help a bit. As I've mentioned in comments, the issue cannot be entirely avoided unless you change to a better approach entirely.

The idea here is to scan the list of processes not once per connection but for all connections that have arrived since the last scan. Since checking connections can be done with a simple hash table lookup in O(1) time, we can process messages much faster.

I chose to go with a simple 1-producer-1-consumer multithreading approach. I think this will work fine because most time is spent in system calls, so Python's global interpreter lock (GIL) is less of an issue. But that requires testing. Possible variations:

1. Use no multithreading, instead read incoming logs nonblocking, then process what you've got
2. Swap the threading module and queue for multiprocessing module
3. Use multiple consumer threads and maybe batch block sizes to have multiple scans through the process list in parallel

```py
import psutil
import queue
import threading


def receive_logs(consumer_queue):
    """Placeholder for actual code reading iptables log"""
    for connection in log:
        nettup = (connection.src, int(connection.spt),
                  connection.dst, int(connection.dpt))
        additional_info = connection.additional_info
        consumer_queue.put((nettup, additional_info))
```

The log reading is not part of the posted code, so this is just some placeholder.

Now we consume all queued connections in a second thread:

```py
def get_procs(producer_queue):
    # 1. Construct a set of connections to search for
    #    Blocks until at least one available
    nettup, additional_info = producer_queue.get()
    connections = {nettup: additional_info}
    try: # read as many as possible
        while True:
            nettup, additional_info = producer_queue.get_nowait()
            connections[nettup] = additional_info
    except queue.Empty:
        pass
    found = []
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(["pid", "name"]):
        for conn in proc.connections(kind="all"):
            try:
                src = conn.laddr.ip
                spt = conn.laddr.port
                dst = conn.raddr.ip
                dpt = conn.raddr.port
            except AttributeError: # not an IP address
                continue
            nettup = (src, spt, dst, dpt)
            if nettup in connections:
                additional_info = connections[nettup]
                found.append((proc, nettup, additional_info))
    found_connections = {nettup for _, nettup, _ in found}
    lost = [(nettup, additional_info)
            for nettup, additional_info in connections.items()
            if not nettup in found_connections]
    return found, lost
```

I don't really understand parts of the posted code in the question, such as the `if flag.is_set(): return proc_info` part so I just left those out. Also, I got rid of some of the less pythonic and potentially slow parts such as `hasattr()`. Adapt as needed.

Now we tie it all together by calling the consumer repeatedly and starting both threads:

```py
def consume(producer_queue):
    while True:
        found, lost = get_procs(producer_queue)
        for proc, (src, spt, dst, dpt), additional_info in found:
            print(f"pid={proc.pid},name={proc.name()}")


def main():
    producer_consumer_queue = queue.SimpleQueue()
    producer = threading.Thread(
        target=receive_logs, args=((producer_consumer_queue, ))
    consumer = threading.Thread(
        target=consume, args=((producer_consumer_queue, ))
    consumer.start()
    producer.start()
    consumer.join()
    producer.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I have been trying to adapt this code to my project since I first saw it. But I stuck in some point. In `receive_logs` function I need to add additional info to `producer_consumer_queue` besides `nettup`. But if I do this how to check `nettup` in `get_procs` function with `if nettup in connections`? I thought of doing it with a `for` loop, but wouldn't that slow down the code again?

Comment: @serhatcelik You can carry more information by changing from a set to a dict. I've adapted the code

Comment: I think there is something wrong with `except queue.Empty` because if iptables keep writing logs, queue will never be empty for a long time. And this causes not to execute psutil functions for a time. Result: PID won't be found :(

Comment: @serhatcelik That would mean the producer generates log messages faster than you can even transfer them to the consumer. That seems unlikely. Whatever you use to read the logs should be slower than that. However, if that is a concern, you can limit the batch size to e.g. 1000 messages. And if you replace the ```SimpleQueue``` with a proper ```Queue```, you can limit its size so that you don't run out of memory

Comment: When I implemented and tried the code yesterday, it seemed fine, but today I started getting weird errors. When I try to read any line with `f.readline()` sometimes the line is not complete and half is missing. Sometimes the script made the computer so tired that my computer became unresponsive and crashed. I had tried using `queue.get_nowait()` instead of `queue.get()` in `get_procs()`. Could it be because of this? The reason I did this was to set the 'global' flag to True when `SIGINT` arrived, otherwise `queue.get()` waits forever...

Comment: @serhatcelik I have no idea what you are reading from because you never showed that part of your code, so I cannot comment on the first part. As for the second, switching to ```get_nowait``` would result in a busy-loop. There are better solutions. a) use the timeout parameter in ```get()``` to check the flag. b) Set the thread to daemon and just let it die when the process dies instead of joining it c) transmit a special "Stop" signal object through the queue. For example an empty tuple or a None would work

Comment: I edited the question. Added section of code used to read log file.

Comment: @serhatcelik Oh, you are literally parsing log files. Well, in that case you race the syslog writing process (and potentially logrotate truncating the files periodically). I guess at the very least you should check that the line you just read ends with a ```\n```, otherwise you might have caught a partially written line. Alternatively you could use iptables' ULOG module and parse netlink messages directly instead of the log files. There are some python modules out there to help with that

Comment: @serhatcelik you can also configure syslog to send messages to a named pipe. Reading from that is atomic and you don't have to check for updates, just keep reading as messages arrive https://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf

Comment: In the `get_procs()` function, the `connections[nettup] = additional_info` line of code causes the packets to be overwritten with the same `nettup`, but different `additional_info`. Any ideas how to fix this? For example, `[nettup + (unique_id)]` for `connection` keys...

Comment: @serhatcelik you are checking for every single packet? No wonder your performance is so crucial. Why not search only for new connections? Just keep track of the connection state while parsing the log. You can also make different log rules with different prefixes for different connection states to make the parsing easier

Comment: @serhatcelik Also to answer your original question, you can swap the dict for a ```collections.defaultdict(list)``` and then use ```connections[nettup].append(additional_info)``` to create a list of payloads